# Questions about recursive methods for generating a tree

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, arraylist, tree

I am trying to understand a simple spell checker program. Basically the program read a dictionary file, and put the words in a tree. When it performs the check function, it takes one word at a time from the file for checking, and checks if this word is in the tree, using `retrieve()`.

I don't understand how this "add" method works. It is supposed to add the words from the dictionary to a tree structure. Please explain how this works?

```
   private static BinarySearchTree<StringItem, String> tree = new BinarySearchTree<StringItem, String>();
  //Does this create a tree with StringItems as nodes? 
  //In which part does this method assign value to the tree nodes?


   private static ArrayList<String> dictionary;//number is the number of strings in the dictionary

   private static TreeNode<StringItem> add (int number) { // adds to the tree
   //the numberOfWords has been counted in other methods. 

    if (numberOfWords < 1) {
        return null;
    }

    TreeNode<StringItem> left = add(number / 2); //What does this do?

    StringItem word = new StringItem(dictionary.remove(0) + "");

    TreeNode<StringItem> right = add((number - 1) / 2);

    return new TreeNode<StringItem>(word, left, right); // I don't understand this part.
    //which node are we returning here? 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html) *really* good implementation of a Binary Search Tree written by the folks at Princeton (as a matter of fact - check out all the *really* good implementations they've published for all sorts of fundamental algorithms [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/))

I'm a little unclear about what your specific question is, but lets start with this:

```
private static BinarySearchTree<StringItem, String> tree = ...
//Does this create a tree with String items as nodes?
```

I think it will help if you think of the BST as being more like a map (with keys of one type mapped to values of another type) rather than a simple list of objects of a single type. If we look at the implementation linked to above, I think this is a bit clearer:

```
public class BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private class Node {
        private Key key;           // sorted by key
        private Value val;         // associated data
        private Node left, right;  // left and right subtrees
        private int N;             // number of nodes in subtree
        ...
    }
    ...
    private Node put(Node x, Key key, Value val) {
        if (x == null) return new Node(key, val, 1);
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
        if      (cmp < 0) x.left  = put(x.left,  key, val);
        else if (cmp > 0) x.right = put(x.right, key, val);
        else              x.val   = val; 
        x.N = 1 + size(x.left) + size(x.right);
        return x;
     }
  ...
}
```

Note that the type parameters are explicitly named `Key` and `Value` here, which should reinforce what I was saying above. Also note that a `Node` contains both a key *and* a value - the value is the "payload", the actual data being being stored, while the key is used for sorting and organizing the tree (hence `Key` must implement `Comparable`). As an aside, note that instead of `add()`, the equivalent method here is called `put()`, which I think is also clearer because we're accustomed to calling `put(k, v)` on map-like structures and `add(t)` on lists (I'm wondering whether this might have played a role in your confusion)

Like I said though, I'm not entirely sure what you're confused about. I've said what I've said here because it seems like you're asking specifically about the type parameters, but you're unclear on something else post a comment and I'll update.

(That said, I included the entire method above because, if what you're really trying to  understand is how BSTs function in general, that's a very important method to understand. Go through and figure out exactly what each line is doing and why its's being done that way. Then do the same for `get()`, and you'll be on your way).

Comment: Many thanks! and thanks for the very useful materials. I can see that the put method you wrote is for assigning a value to a node based on its key? But I can't see which part of the code in the add method I posted does this function. I commented my questions in the code. Thanks again.